# Isobaric spin $T = 0$ and Pauli-exclusion principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, pauli-exclusion-principle

I was reading  a Book of Nuclear Physics (Concepts of Nuclear Physics by Bernard L. Cohen), in which he discusses the concept of Isobaric spin T and defines it by saying

> We see that only wave functions with even $l$, $S=0$ (Space symmetric, Spin anti-symmetric) or odd $l$, $S=1$ satisfy the Pauli exclusion principle. These states called $T=1$ states, where $T$ is isobaric spin. Other states of the two nucleons system, those with even $l$, $S=1$ or odd $l$ or $S=0$. We see that $T=1$ states are available to any of the three two-nucleon systems, proton-proton, proton-neutron, and neutron-neutron, whereas $T=0$ states are available only to the proton-neutron system because it does not consist of identical particles and hence need not satisfy the Pauli-exclusion principal.

(Book page No.39, last paragraph)

In the last line, Cohen writes that the proton-neutron system does not need to satisfy the Pauli-exclusion Principle. Can someone please justify this?

Answer (score 3):

The proton and the neutron have the same value of isobaric spin, but different isobaric spin projections ($\pm \frac{1}{2}$). This is like an electron having spin-half, and then being either "spin-up" or "spin-down". As they have different quantum numbers, the proton and neutron can occupy the same state, that is, Pauli's principle does not forbid this. This would not be possible for a proton-proton, or a neutron-neuron, system though.

Comment: Why T=0 consist of proton-neutron while T=1consist all of the combinations.

Comment: It may be helpful to think of the two-electron case. $T=0$ corresponds to the spin-singlet, which is an antisymmetric combination of up and down spins (proton-neutron). The $T=1$ is the triplet, which contains up-up (i.e. proton-proton), down-down (neutron-neutron), and a symmetric combination of up-down (proton-neutron).

Comment: How $T=0$ case is corresponding to spin-singlet , all I know it corresponds to even $l$ and $S=1$ or odd l and $S=0$.and Thus they will not satisfy the Pauli-exclusion principal as they have symmetric wave functions. but I don't understand the fact that the state is only  availble to neutron-proton pair.

Comment: Let's look at the $T=1$ states. Firstly there are the $S=1$ states, which we can write schematically as $|p,p \rangle$ and $|n,n\rangle$. Then there is the $S=0$ state $|p,n\rangle + |n,p\rangle$. There is one other combination, $|p,n\rangle - |n,p\rangle$, which corresponds to $T=0$. Clearly this would vanish for two protons or two neutrons, as a consequence of the Pauli principle.

Answer (score 1):

Pauli's Exclusion Principle only applies to identical fermions. It's the basic fundamental. What more do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Protons and neutrons are 2 **different** particles. Pauli's principle applies only to **identical** particles. When the two particles form a whole, they become indistinguishable. Which reflects itself in their common wavefunction. This becomes anti-symmetric. There is not a separate part of this wavefunction that refers to their spin, which would be the case if both were, say, electrons.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) article on Wikipedia.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles

Comment: It is written that identical means indistinguishable and there two categories of these particle bosons and fermions here both are fermions  so they should be identical.

Comment: Both are fermions, that's true. But they are distinguishable fermions.